# How to switch JProfiler launcher in Eclipse integration

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jprofiler

The JProfiler plugin of my Eclipse IDE (Eclipse 3.5) is configured to work with JProfiler 6.x which is installed on my machine.

I'd like to configure my Eclipse to work with JProfiler 4.x which is also installed on my machine. How can I do it through Eclipse UI?

Tried to find this option in Run --> 'Profile Configuration' but couldn't find this option.

I am actually look for the dialog in which I can replace the path to the correct JProfiler location.

Answer (score 4):

in Eclipse:

Window --> preferences --> JProfiler
...